# Passing buttons down to component with callbacks

Tags: reactjs

What if I have a table, which consists of rows and my container of that table wants to pass buttons down to the table but handle the clicks itself? See beneath for untested code which illustrates the situation. If I do this, it won't work because `data-employee` will become `[object Object]` obviously. How would I go about passing buttons, but also making sure EmployeeTable will be able to attach the employee to the button?

```
class TableContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  rowButtonClick(e) {
    // Get the employee from onClick event somehow
  }

  render () {

    let rowButtons = [
      employee => (<button onClick={this.rowButtonClick} data-employee={employee}>View</button>),
      employee => (<button onClick={this.rowButtonClick} data-employee={employee}>Delete</button>)
    ]

    return (
      <EmployeeTable rowButtons={rowButtons} />
    );
  }
}

class EmployeeTable extends React.Component {

  /** Fetches it's own employees in state **/

  render () {
    return (
      <table>
        {this.state.employees.map((employee, key) => {
        <tr>
          <td>{employee.name}</td>
          <td>
            {this.props.employeeButtons.map((btn, key) => {
              return btn(employee);
            })}
          </td>
        </tr>
        })}
      </table>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to pass the buttons array like that.

Refactored

```
//***************************************************/

class TableContainer extends React.Component {

  viewEmployee(employee) {
      console.log('Called view on:', employee.name)
  }

  deleteEmployee(employee) {
      console.log('Called delete on:', employee.name)
  }

  render () {

    return (
      <EmployeeTable 
        viewEmployee={(employee) => this.viewEmployee(employee)}
        deleteEmployee={(employee) => this.deleteEmployee(employee)} 
      />
    );
  }
}

//***************************************************/

class EmployeeTable extends React.Component {

  /** Fetches it's own employees in state **/

  render () {
    return (
      <table>
        {this.state.employees.map(employee => {
          <tr>
            <td>{employee.name}</td>
            <td>
              <button onClick={() => this.props.viewEmployee(employee)}>View</button>
              <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteEmployee(employee)}>Delete</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        })}
      </table>
    )
  }
}

//***************************************************/
```

Comment: You're half right about the button itself but mistaken about the array, 
What if let's say he needs to reuse it for different views?
Or have different buttons with different text or style?
This is very hardcoded and not flexible and would require changes into the code for every new requirement...

Comment: Yes, OB Fullstack Kenobi is right. I need to pass the buttons as an array to make it flexible. In matter of fact, I first had them as hard coded elements, but now converted them to this array of elements so I can decide on a higher level what buttons are to be used. This answer is not right, for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a closure to solve your problem.

```
class TableContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  rowButtonClick(employee) {
    return (event) => {
      //Add employee handling here.
    };
  }

  render () {

    let rowButtons = [
      employee => (<button onClick={this.rowButtonClick(employee)} data-employee={employee}>View</button>),
      employee => (<button onClick={this.rowButtonClick(employee)} data-employee={employee}>Delete</button>)
    ]

    return (
      <EmployeeTable rowButtons={rowButtons} />
    );
  }
}
```

This will ensure that the employee information is always available to the inner function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that won't work, `employee` is a object which will render `[object Object]` in the `data-employee` attribute.

Comment: @Ambidex agreed it won't change data-employee. I was giving a solution to the on click comment: // Get the employee from onClick event somehow.

I don't know why you exactly need the data-employee field but if you try to put an object here it would always give you [object Object]. You can try to JSON.stringify [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify )[link] it and then when you want to use it, do JSON.parse to get the object back from the string.

Answer (score -1):

Pass the button as component that receives a prop representing the on click action and another prop that represent the data for that click.

Say:

```
const EmployeeTableButton = (props) => {
    return <button onClick={() => props.rowButtonClick(props.employee)}>{props.actionName}</button>)
}

class TableContainer extends React.Component {

  rowButtonClick = (action) => (employee) {
    // get the wanted action from the pre scoped action param
    // then execute it with the employee param passed by the renderer 
  }

  render () {

    let rowButtons = [
      {
          actionName: 'View',
          rowButtonClick: this.rowButtonClick('view')
      },
      {
          actionName: 'Delete',
          rowButtonClick: this.rowButtonClick('delete')
      }
    ]

    return (
      <EmployeeTable rowButtons={rowButtons} />
    );
  }
}

class EmployeeTable extends React.Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <table>
        {this.state.employees.map((employee, key) => {
        <tr>
          <td>{employee.name}</td>
          <td>
            {
                this.props.employeeButtons.map((btn) => (
                   <EmployeeTableButton {...btn} employee={employee} />
                ) 
            }
          </td>
        </tr>
        })}
      </table>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, on first glance this does seem to be a solution to my problem. Only thing I think is a bit of a shame is that I'm unable to pass the <button> elements themselves to the EmployeeTable, this makes it a bit less flexible. I'll test this soon, I'll get back to voting / marking as answer if applicable.

Comment: @Ambidex if it helped you feel free to upvote and select as the right answer